# Comunicar varias consolas de windows a la vez

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera saber si es posible abrir múltiples ventanas `cmd` de windows desde un programa en python y posteriormente mandarle mensajes algo como un cliente servidor pero entre 2 ventanas de cmd abiertas desde el mismo modulo:

**Ejemplo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por el momento lo que he intentado es lo siguiente

```
import subprocess
import sys
import threading

def cmd():
    proceso = subprocess.Popen(["cmd","hola"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proceso.stdin.write("hola".encode())
    proceso.wait()

for i in range(4):
    threading.Thread(target=cmd,daemon=True).start()
```

básicamente la función cmd tiene como función el abrir una nueva ventana `cmd` con el mensaje hola, esta acción debe de repetirse 4 veces, es decir al final habrá 4 ventanas `hola` y la ventana principal

pero no funciona y solo se muestra la `cmd` principal

Comment: No me imagino porque querrías hacer algo así, sin embargo, podrías usar sockets para comunicar los procesos entre si. Y ejecutar los 4 procesos desde uno solo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede usar win32

```py
import time

from win32com import client
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId

def create_cmd():
    shell = client.Dispatch("WScript.shell")
    shell.run("cmd.exe")
    time.sleep(1)
    window = GetForegroundWindow()
    pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)[1]
    shell.AppActivate(pid)
    shell.SendKeys("ECHO Hola {ENTER}")

for i in range(4):
    create_cmd()
```

El código lo he adaptado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061437).